# What is the relationship between average of a rolling intercept and the intercept from a regression over the entire period?

Tags: least-squares, intercept, moving-window

If i calculate rolling (e.g. 3 periods back) intercepts for a time series using OLS, is the average of these rolling intercepts then in some way related to the intercept from an OLS of the entire series?

Below is an example - the average of the rolling intercepts is 1.05, while the intercept from regression on the whole series is 2.21.

[image]

Comment: Contemplate this: add a huge value $a$ to $y_3$ and subtract $a$ from $y_9.$  Consider the effects this will have on the mean of the rolling intercepts and the overall intercept.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your rolling intercepts.  Could you explain how you are computing them?

Comment: In excel: INTERCEPT([2.03, 2.27, 2.43], [1.85,1.83, 1.57])=4.11

Comment: And then just pull down the formula, so each intercept is based on the last 3 values of x and y

Comment: I am using `R`.  It is more trustworthy than Excel's solution.  In the case given in your comment, `R` computes an intercept of 4.1367760.  (One way to display this result is with the command `lm(c(2.03, 2.27, 2.43) ~ c(1.85, 1.83, 1.57))`.)  In some of the other cases its calculation differs even more from what you report.  The formula you give is not a valid Excel formula, but when I put those values into the range A1:B3, the formula `=INTERCEPT(A1:A3, B1:B3)` correctly returns 4.136776.

Comment: You are right, the difference from 4.11 is just because of rounding of the values shown in my example.  The formula i wrote should have been "=INTERCEPT({2.03,2.27, 2.43}, {1.85,1.83, 1.57})", which evaluates to 4.137.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  So let's turn to the problem: did you discover what happens when you carry out the experiment described in my first comment?

Comment: Yes i did - when adding a large value, and then subtracting it, the average of rolling intercepts increases much more than the intercept across all y's.. So the explanation is just that the rolling intercept mean is more sensitive to outliers?

Comment: That's a pretty good summary.  The nature of these "outliers" matters, though: the principle is that when you change the value of a response (y) near one extreme of the regressor (x), the fitted line will change greatly, but when you change the response near the mean of the regressors, the fitted line may change little.  Indeed, in your data there are two pairs with identical regressor values; changing the responses without changing the *average* response within a pair doesn't change the overall fitted line whatsoever--but it can change some of the running fits dramatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct relationship between these two estimation methods, and their interaction depends on the underlying data in a complex way.  To see this, we can derive the formulae for the two estimators.  Using the whole dataset, the **OLS intercept estimator** in simple linear regression can be written as:

$$\hat{\beta}_0 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \Bigg[ y_i - x_i \cdot \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i) - \tfrac{1}{n} (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i) (\sum_{i=1}^n y_i)}{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2) - \tfrac{1}{n} (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2} \Bigg].$$

Suppose you have $n$ data points and you compute the average of the rolling-intercepts, each with a window of $m<n$ data points.  For each $k=0,...,n-m$ the individual **OLS rolling-intercepts** (each taken over values $i = k+1,...,k+m$) can be written as:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\hat{\beta}_0^{(k)} 
&=\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m} \Bigg[ y_i - x_i \cdot \frac{(\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m} x_i y_i) - \tfrac{1}{m} (\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m} x_i) (\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m} y_i)}{(\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m} x_i^2) - \tfrac{1}{m} (\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m} x_i)^2} \Bigg]. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Taking the average of these rolling-intercepts gives:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\hat{\beta}_0^* 
&\equiv \frac{1}{n-m} \sum_{k=0}^{n-m} \hat{\beta}_0^* \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{m(n-m)} \sum_{k=0}^{n-m} \sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m} 
\Bigg[ y_i - x_i \cdot \frac{(\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m} x_i y_i) - \tfrac{1}{m} (\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m} x_i) (\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m} y_i)}{(\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m} x_i^2) - \tfrac{1}{m} (\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m} x_i)^2} \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{m(n-m)} \sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{k=\max(0,i-m)}^{\min(n-m,i-1)} 
\Bigg[ y_i - x_i \cdot \frac{(\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m} x_i y_i) - \tfrac{1}{m} (\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m} x_i) (\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m} y_i)}{(\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m} x_i^2) - \tfrac{1}{m} (\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m} x_i)^2} \Bigg]. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

As can be seen, this second estimator has a complicated form, and does not reduce to a function of the OLS estimator for the whole dataset.